# Sticky positioning isn't working on text box

Tags: javascript, html, css

The sticky positioning is working on the canvas element, but not the text for whatever reason. Also, the canvas seems to ignore the margin of the t-shirt and ends up on top, which I also cannot fix. This is my github: https://github.com/GitItGurlll/ReJuicin8Web/tree/draft

Please help!!!!

I've tried margin, padding, different positioning, nothing works.
**CSS**

```
.flashy {
  height: 500vh;
  display: flex;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 40%;
  top: 30%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 520px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -0%);
}

#scroll-container {
  height: 500vh; /* Set the desired height for the scroll container */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
  
#text-element,
#subtext-element {
  position: fixed;
  width: fit-content;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
  
#text-element {
  top: 18%;
  left: 48%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#subtext-element {
top: 30%;
left: 49%;
display: block;
font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="flashy">
    </div>
        <div class="imp">
        <canvas id="hero-lightpass"></canvas>  
    </div> 

    <div id="scroll-container">
        <div id="text-element">Initial Text</div>
        <div id="subtext-element">Initial Text</div>
      </div>          
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    ('.parallax-container').css('background-position', 'center ' + scrollTop / 2 + 'px');
  });

          // Canvas settings
        const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const container = document.getElementById('scroll-container');
        const textElement = document.getElementById('text-element');
        const subtextElement = document.getElementById('subtext-element')
        const totalSections = 10; // Number of sections to divide the container height

        canvas.width=1158;
        canvas.height=1000;

        
        // Preloading images to drastically improve performance
        const currentFrame = index => (`Drink/Green${index.toString()}.jpg`);
        console.log(currentFrame)
        const frameCount = 148; // There 148 images for that animation-sequence to load
        const images = [];

        const preloadImages = () => {
            for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
                images[i] = new Image(); // This is functionally equivalent to document.createElement('img').
                images[i].src = currentFrame(i);
            }
        };

        preloadImages();


        // Draw the first image
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = currentFrame(1);
        img.onload = function(){
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }


        // Scroll interactions
        const html = document.getElementsByTagName('html');
        
        const texts = [
            "Rejuvenate",
            'New Text 2',
            'New Text 3',
            'New Text 4',
            'New Text 5',
            'New Text 6',
            'New Text 7',
            'New Text 8',
            'New Text 9',
            'New Text 10'
          ];

          const subtexts = [
            "Orange, Pineapple, Lime, Ginger, Carrot, Red Apple",
            'New Text 2',
            'New Text 3',
            'New Text 4',
            'New Text 5',
            'New Text 6',
            'New Text 7',
            'New Text 8',
            'New Text 9',
            'New Text 10'
          ];
          
          let currentSectionIndex = 0;
    let isInCurrentSection = false;
          
        
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {  
            const scrollTop = html[0].scrollTop;
            // console.log('scrollTop: ', scrollTop);
            // console.log('html.scrollHeight: ', html[0].scrollHeight);
            // console.log('window.innerHeight: ', window.innerHeight);
            const maxScrollTop = html[0].scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
            const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
            const frameIndex = Math.min(
                frameCount - 1,
                Math.floor(scrollFraction * frameCount)
            );
            // console.log('FrameIndex', frameIndex);

            requestAnimationFrame(() => context.drawImage(images[frameIndex + 2], 0, 0));

            const containerHeight = container.offsetHeight;
            const sectionHeight = containerHeight / totalSections;
            const sectionIndex = Math.floor(scrollTop / sectionHeight);


            if (((scrollFraction * 100) % 10) ==  0) {
                currentSectionIndex = ((scrollFraction * 10) / 10)
            }

              if (sectionIndex !== currentSectionIndex) {
                textElement.style.opacity = '0';
                subtextElement.style.opacity = '0';
                setTimeout(() => {
                  textElement.textContent = texts[currentSectionIndex];
                  subtextElement.textContent = subtexts[currentSectionIndex];
                  textElement.style.opacity = '1';
                  subtextElement.style.opacity = '1';
                
                }, 400); // Change the duration (in milliseconds) to control the fade in time
                currentSectionIndex = sectionIndex;
              }
        });
```

Comment: you should provide a minimal reproducible example. And this could be caused by all the unclosed <div> tags in your code.

Comment: I closed my divs.

Answer (score 0):

So the canvas is not ignoring the margin of the t-shirt. You simple use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` on it, which translates it into the t-shirt image. Removing that line shows the image right below the t-shirt.

The sticky text part is not at all debugable for me. For that you would need to give a minimal reproducible example, else I can't debug all of the stuff thats happening there.

Comment: please check again, i edited it.

Comment: So the code you added seems to do what you want, right? Or is anything wrong there?